# Trying to create a new Prism Uwp project from blank a "App Universal Windows"

Tags: prism

Hope someone can give me some hints of my problem.
I'm starting with a blank "App Universal Windows" (UWP).
I'm upgrade to the latest "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.2.2"
I'm using Nuget to install Prism and selecting the Prism.Unity v6.3.0-pre1.
(I have also tried the 6.2 with the same symptom.)

Changeing the App.xaml.cs to:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Prism.Unity.Windows;

namespace Bituc
{
    sealed partial class App : PrismUnityApplication
    {
        public App()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override Task OnLaunchApplicationAsync(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate("Main", null);
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
}    }    }
```

This gives me this complie errors:
Error   CS0263  Partial declarations of 'App' must not specify different base
Error   CS0115  'App.OnLaunchApplicationAsync(LaunchActivatedEventArgs)': no suitable method found to override.
Error   CS0103  The name 'NavigationService' does not exist in the current context.

This is my project.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.2.2",
"Prism.Unity": "6.3.0-pre1"},
"frameworks": {"uap10.0": {}},
"runtimes": {
"win10-arm": {},
"win10-arm-aot": {},
"win10-x86": {},
"win10-x86-aot": {},
"win10-x64": {},
"win10-x64-aot": {}
}
```

What am i missing?
Thank's for any suggestions.
Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your `App.xaml` look like this?

```
<Application x:Class="BorealDesigner.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
...
</Application>
```

If so, also change **Application** to **PrismUnityApplication**, as that's what the error message tells you: if you define a class in two files, you cannot have it derive from `Application` in one file but `PrismUnityApplication` in the other.

BTW, probably lesser known fact: you need only one of the class declaration files to state the base class. The typical `: UserControl` you find in the code behind is superfluous...

Comment: Thanks. This was the problem.

Comment: Have you considered accepting the answer? Just in case someone else with a similar problem stumbles upon this...

Comment: Thanks for the remainder, missed it.