# Correct class name for the code-behind partial class to correspond to the one specified in the XAML file?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, partial-classes

I am following this tutorial here: https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/getting-started.html

It first modifies the class used in *App.xaml* as follows:

```
<prism:PrismApplication
    x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
    ...
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/">
...
</prism:PrismApplication>
```

Then, in the *App.xaml.cs* code-behind file, it derives the `App` class from class `PrismApplication` (replacing the standard WPF `Application` class) like so:

```
public partial class App : PrismApplication
...
```

When I replicated the above steps, I got the following error:

> CS0263 Partial declaration of 'App' must not specify different base
> classes

Looking up the error, I came across the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40616616/
which says that you need only specify the base class in one of the partial class declaration files, and that usually, the specification in the code-behind file is unnecessary.

Accordingly, I changed the partial class definition in the code-behind file as follows:

```
public partial class App
```

And sure enough, the error went away.

My question: Since `PrismApplication` is obviously not the correct way to specify the base class name in the code-behind file for the above case (corresponding to `prism:PrismApplication`), what is?

Comment: There's more than one `PrismApplication` - one for each container, i.e. one in `Prism.DryIoc`, one in `Prism.Unity`... you may want to check the namespaces and/or reference it explicitly in code behind (with full name space).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Official samples do explicit inheritance from base class in .xaml.cs like [this](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/blob/master/02-Regions/Regions/App.xaml.cs). Try deleting bin and obj folders of your project as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46261221/4108016), it might resolve the issue.